# Minimum Number of People Such That No Two People Know the Same Two People

Tags: graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

In a population of $n$ people, each person knows $k$ other people and if person A knows person B then person B knows person A.  However, no two people, A and C, know the same two people B and D.  What is the minimum $n$ such that this is possible for a given $k$?  Or, in other words, what's the minimum number of nodes that must exist such that it is possible to connect each node to $k$ other nodes while not allowing a circuit of length 4?

I don't have much on this problem yet besides a weak lower bound of $n\geq k^2-k+1$.

In the graphs below, an edge means that the two people it connects know each other.  In 1), this is a demonstration of what we don't want, both A and C know D and B.  In 2) these are configurations that work for k=2.  For k=2, $n=3$ and $n>4$ work.  In 3) n=10, and this is the smallest possible configuration for k=3.

[image: various node set ups here]

Comment: here's a related question for you,  how many lines can connect the vertices of a regular n-gon ?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee, n choose 2 - n.  I was trying to find something along these lines that relates to the problem.  I had no such luck however.

Comment: $T_{n-1}$ is actually what I was looking for, where $T_n$ is the nth triangular number . That's the maximum number of lines needed to connect everyone in a set of n. which of the number of connections for each is above k ? sorry just coming at it from a different set of knowledge I guess.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theorem_on_friends_and_strangers  is in effect what you are extending I think. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xdiL-ADRTxQ may also be helpful to your thought process.

Comment: @Roddy MacPhee.  I'm not too sure what you mean by "which of the number of connections for each is above k."  I've given up on a mathematical approach to this and I'm writing a code to check for this instead.  I thought of a way to do this by having a nxn grid in which each row/column must have k dots. a dot in row i and column j means that person i knows person j and person j knows person i.

Comment: The labelling in your first diagram is confusing because you've switched from "A and B know both C and D" to "A and C know both B and D". These are equivalent, of course, but the switch is unnecessary and misleading.

Comment: If there is a projective plane of order $k-1$ then $n=2(k^2-k+1)$ works, a weak upper bound which is just twice your weak lower bound. As the graph in this case is bipartite, there are no cycles of odd length, as well as no cycles of length $4.$

Comment: For odd $k$ your weak lower bound becomes $n\ge k^2-k+2.$